# Falso erro ao abrir documento decifrado com biblioteca Crypto do Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, criptografia, aes

Testei o seguinte script em Python, usando Python 2.7.9, com algumas adaptações feitas por mim, disponível em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900280/how-can-i-encrypt-docx-files-with-aes-pycrypto-without-corrupting-the-files:

```
# Cifra e decifra documentos nos formatos .pdf, .docx e .rtf
# Adaptacao de Marcelo Ferreira Zochio

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

def pad(s):
    padding_size = AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size
    return s + b"\0" * padding_size, padding_size

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    message, padding_size = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    enc_bytes = iv + cipher.encrypt(message) + bytes([padding_size])    
    return enc_bytes

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return plaintext

def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()    
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + ".crp", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open('decifrado_' + file_name, 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

key = 'chave'
hash_object = hashlib.md5(key.encode())

while True:
    filename = raw_input("Arquivo a ser trabalhado: ")
    en_de = raw_input("En (cifrar) ou De (decifrar)?")
    if en_de.upper() == 'EN':
        encrypt_file(filename, hash_object.hexdigest())
    elif en_de.upper() == 'DE':
        decrypt_file(filename, hash_object.hexdigest())
    else:
        print("Escolher en ou de!")

    cont = raw_input("Continuar?")
    if cont.upper() == 'N':
        break
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, porém, ao abrir documentos em formato .docx e .odt decifrados (apagando a extensão .crp e deixando a original) o Windows avisa que o documento está corrompido, e se eu desejo recuperar esse documento; escolhendo sim, ele o recupera normalmente e então é só salvá-lo.

Isso não acontece com .pdf e nem com .txt. Tem algo a haver com a formatação de caracteres do Word ou do Open Office?

Comment: Para ter certeza que seu programa está cifrando e decifrando arquivos corretamente, sugiro que você calcule o *hash* do arquivo antes da cifragem e depois da decifragem, se os *hashes* não forem iguais, certamente o arquivo foi corrompido. No Windows, você pode usar o [WinMD5](http://www.winmd5.com/) para obter os *hashes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AES`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) é um algoritmo de [cifragem de bloco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_bloco), e funciona com blocos de tamanho fixo de `16 bytes` ou `128 bits`, nem mais, nem menos.

Isso significa que sua implementação deve levar alguns fatores *importantes* em consideração:

1. O `AES` trabalha **somente** com dados de entrada de tamanhos múltiplos de `16 bytes`;
2. Dados **menores** que o tamanho do bloco precisam ser "completados" (*padding*) até atingirem o tamanho do bloco;
3. Dados **maiores** que o tamanho do bloco precisam ser "fragmentados" em pedaços do mesmo tamanho do bloco, e claro, "completados" quando necessário;
4. Blocos de tamanhos menores que foram "completados" (*padding*) durante a operação de cifragem precisam ser "truncados" (*unpadding*) a fim de se recuperar o dado em seu tamanho original durante a operação de decifragem;
5. Ao cifrar arquivos, seu o tamanho original deve ser armazenado juntamente com o dado cifrado para viabilizar a truncagem (*unpadding*) do ultimo bloco durante a operação de decifragem;
6. A cifragem e decifragem de arquivos deve acontecer em partes (*chunks*), evitando armazenar o arquivo inteiro na memória de uma só vez antes do porcessamento.

Sua implementação viola o `item 5`, que certamente, é a causa da destruição dos dados originais.

Outro ponto é que sua implementação grava o arquivo cifrado em representação `base64`, isso não é necessário, os dados cifrados podem ser gravados em formato binário.

Sua implementação carrega o arquivo a ser cifrado/decifrado completamente para a memória! Isso cria uma limitação se a memória disponível for menor que o tamanho do arquivo.

Com base [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/) e [nesta](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto) referência, segue uma classe capaz de cifrar e decifrar arquivos e dados da maneira correta sem  corromper o conteúdo:

```
import os
import hashlib
import base64
import struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

chunksize = 64 * 1024
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

class AESCipher:

    def __init__( self, key ):
        keydigest = hashlib.sha1(key).digest()
        self.key = keydigest[:16]

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) )

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))

    def encrypt_file( self, in_filename, out_filename ):
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
        with open( in_filename, 'rb' ) as infile:
            with open( out_filename, 'wb' ) as outfile:
                outfile.write( struct.pack('<Q', filesize) )
                outfile.write(iv)
                while True:
                    chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                    if len(chunk) == 0:
                        break
                    elif len(chunk) % BS != 0:
                        chunk += ' ' * (BS - len(chunk) % BS)
                    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

    def decrypt_file( self, in_filename, out_filename ):
        with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
            origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
            iv = infile.read(16)
            decryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
                while True:
                    chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                    if len(chunk) == 0:
                        break
                    outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
                outfile.truncate(origsize)


# Definindo uma chave
chave = "Oi! Eu sou uma chave de tamanho indefinido!"

# Cria uma instancia do Objeto De/Cifrador AES
aes = AESCipher( chave )

# Testando cifragem de dados/texto
cifrado = aes.encrypt( "Eu sou uma mensagem super secreta." )
decifrado = aes.decrypt( cifrado )

print cifrado
print decifrado

# Testando cifragem de arquivo
aes.encrypt_file( "secreto.txt", "cifrado.bin" )

# Testando decifragem do arquivo
aes.decrypt_file( "cifrado.bin", "decifrado.txt" )
```

Possível Saída:

```
$ python AESCipher.py
zceFuiV9RTqFsBSY2AYcWMUXqYqI5+3yR08DsH/GeofcSFsg1KpjN4KKL+MaUq4Qmfa9uMFjXL4Ng41giNMGUQ==
Eu sou uma mensagem super secreta.
```

Verificando assinatura `MD5` (*hash*) dos arquivos:

```
$ md5sum secreto.txt cifrado.bin decifrado.txt
77daefe247686325a5da08e556aba4f0  secreto.txt
e2645f7b2d0af5f79b5108707bb3a13d  cifrado.bin
77daefe247686325a5da08e556aba4f0  decifrado.txt
```

Comment: Mas você consegue aponta ro que está errado no código da pergunta?
Por que assim, você pode até resolver um problema pontual do O.P. , mas qualquer um vindo depois vai poder só ou copiar e colar o seu código todo, ou ficar um tempão comparando os códigos para descobrir o que estava errado.

No meu entender este site fica  bem mais útill quando explicamos os problemas dos códigos (o que não impede de forma alguma que se poste o código inteiro funcional junto com a explicação)

Comment: @jsbueno: feito!

Comment: Valeu mesmo!! :-)